# underscore memoize from scratch

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In studying underscore `memoize`, I do not understand the line:
`var argString = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments,"_");`. I know that it is creating a string of the arguments, but how is that applicable here?

```
_.memoize = function(func) {
    var output  = {}; 
    return function(){
        var argString = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments,"_");       
        if (output[argString] === undefined){ 
            output[argString] = func.apply(this, arguments); 
        }
        return output[argString];
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the above code, Initially an object is created with name **output**.

Next, key for the object is created based on the arguments.

example: consider a function,

```
function x(a,b,c){
   // argument will be in an array form, but not an Array actually
   console.log(argument) // will give array like structure.
}
```

Now, using  **Array.prototype.join.call(arguments,"_");**  generating dynamic key based on the arguments.

Next,

```
if (output[argString] === undefined){ 
        output[argString] = func.apply(this, arguments); 
       }
```

this will check, dynamically generated key is there or not in **output** object,

if it is there it will return the value without function call otherwise it will call the function and cache the key and value in output object.

Hope you understand the logic behind this.